# Why use adzerk?

Tags: advertising

SO used adzerk to serve adverts.  I'm a bit confused by it though, what's it do and what's the point of it?  Why can't SO serve their own adverts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question [how does Stackoverflow serve ads?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81813/how-does-stackoverflow-serve-ads) should help.